Problems with multiple flask requests
I'm having a problem where I make 2 or 3 requests on the front-end and while one request is in progress it executes another, so it returns several types of errors:
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError) Commands out of sync; you cannot run this command now
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: The instance <OrderItem at 0x268967c8f50> is not linked to a session; the attribute update operation cannot proceed (History of this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/bhk3)
Among other errors
Below is the way I set up the connection and then the way I call it in the request.
class__DBConnectionHandler:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__connection_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}".format(
        )
        self.__engine = None
        self.session = None

    def connect_to_db(self) -> None:
        self.__engine = create_engine(self.__connection_string)

    def create_tables(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.__engine)

    def get_engine(self):
        return self.__engine

    def __enter__(self):
        session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=self.__engine)
        self.session = session_maker()
        return to yourself

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.session.close()

db_connection_handler=__DBConnectionHandler()



def get_all_order_items(self, order_id: int) -> OrderItem:
      with db_connection_handler as database:
          todos_order_items = (
            database.session
            .query(OrderItem, FoodItem)
            .join(FoodItem)
            .filter(OrderItem.orders_id == order_id)  
            .all()
        )
          return todos_order_items

It's requested above as an example, but it calls out a bit of that at the same time.
I've already tried a few ways and I wasn't successful, preferably I would like to just change the connection and solve the problem for the API calls, but if that wasn't the case, that would be fine.

You have a single connection handler, and the session is an instance variable. You have multiple requests entering and exiting the context manager simultaneously.  This design cannot work. You probably need to decouple the engine (which is global) from session creation (which is per request). Review Contextual/Thread-local Sessions.
